# Choose XML Expansion Pack

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-office-2010, templates

I have created a template level addin for word which is initiated when a particular template is opened which shows a new button in the ribbon.  If that button is clicked, it shows an action pane with options to help the user create a new document prefilled by allowing them to choose different options.

The problem is, that if such a document is saved, anyone else who opens that saved document gets the following message:

[image]

How do I stop this from happening?

Does an option exist in word which automatically strips the expansion packs when a document is saved?

Comment: See if [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bowerm/archive/2005/01/11/350461.aspx) (and its comments) help.

Comment: Ever find an answer to this? Seems potentially related to VSTO.

Answer (score 0):

If the XML Template is being used in other computers, check if it is located in the templates folder.

If the XML template disappears after a save, check the link posted by harrymc and make sure you are saving your templates correctly.